# Change login CSS

Tags: filters, css, login

Is there a filter or something that would remove: `html,body {height:100%;}` declaration in the login page? I have made a custom login page and the `html, body {height: 100%;}` is conflicting in my style. Wordpress loads the `html,body {height:100%;}` declaration from wp-admin/css/wp-admin.css and I would like to keep the wp-admin.css file intact. I cannot override the function with `height: auto;`

If there is a better way of doing it please tell me :)

Update 25.07.2013

html,body `{height:auto;}` Will not work somehow I have to remove it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you know you misspelled "height", right?

To override css, you can use the "!important" operator. So you'd use:

```
html,body{height: auto !important;}
```

Also, you are doing something like this in your functions.php, right?

```
function changeLoginCSS() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body{height: auto !important;} 
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'changeLoginCSS' );
```

Comment: ooh lol yeah sorry about the misspelling. In my css its height :). But the problem is that auto will not work. I have to somehow remove it completely :/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you send a link or screenshot?

Comment: [Example image](http://i41.tinypic.com/10cl15l.png)`html,body {height:100%;}` is creating the white block at the bottom [Live web site](http://sportmedia.fi/wp-login.php) Resize the window smaller

Comment: In login-styles.css, "body.login" needs to be changed to "html"

Comment: thanks that did the trick: 1 change body.login to html and add one line `body.login{background: transparent;}`

Comment: Do i have to delete this post? because of solution can be made purely with css.

Comment: I think it's ok, its still relevant to WP. You can mark this as "answered".